# For x in y and x.each do |y| - iterations don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= nodes %> returns an array of location objects:

#<Location:0x7f24858b5078>#<Location:0x7f24858b4d58>#<Location:0x7f24858b4ab0>
```

When I iterate through the nodes, the iteration doesn't work. Instead of listing the nodes under each other (as the code says), the same array as above is shown. If I remove '<%= node %>' from the code, the only thing that is shown by the iteration loop is one single ';'. The iteration runs only once, and without splitting up the array.

```
<%= nodes %>
<% for node in nodes %>
  <%= node %>;<br />
<% end %>
```

What is wrong?

The nodes in the nodes array are arranged by ancestry. (I don't know if this has anything to say, though.)

Comment: Do your node objects have a `to_s` method ? What does it return?

Comment: The locations have a name_nb field. When I try to get the content of this field in the iteration loop, ('<%= node.name_nb %>), I get this error:
undefined method `name_nb' for #<Array:0x7f2483b55be0>

Comment: It seems you have an array of array. Try this: `<% for node in nodes %><%= node.inspect %> <% end %>` and see if it has an array instead of an object.

Comment: It seems like it is an ordered hash (from an ancestry arrange). I dont't know how to iterate through those. I guess I'll have to do some research. :) EDIT: They are nested hashes...

Comment: This is just a part of what I get when I inspect the node:
[#<Location id: 18, location_number: "7", name_nb: "Norge", location_type: "", user_id: nil, created_at: "2011-10-26 07:00:41", updated_at: "2011-10-26 07:00:41", ancestry: "2/3", name_nn: nil, name_en: nil, highest_resource_number: nil, resource_number_base_34: nil, customer_id: 4, group_member_id: nil>, #<OrderedHash {#<Location id: 19, location_number: "8", name_nb: "Ringerike kommune", location_type: "", user_id: nil, created_at: "2011-10-26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I wanted to do the iteration was to edit the nodes "collection" by doing a .select on them. I found a better way to do it, by using a better .where-clause to narrow the collection before it was arranged by ancestry.

Thank's to all for answering!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are not really getting an array of Locations returned.  if you were you would expect to see

```
[#<Location:0x7f24858b5078>,#<Location:0x7f24858b4d58>,#<Location:0x7f24858b4ab0>]
```

so it looks like you Nodes method is what is to blame.  make sure that is returning what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise not to use Ruby's `for` keyword (I haven't seen it for a long time anyways) but to use `.each` instead. ERB might handle `for x in y` incorrectly (especially if you don't provide the optional `do` keyword at the end).

Try this instead:

```
<% nodes.each do |node| %>
  <%= node %>;<br/>
<% end %>
```